# Referência não definida para "crypt" erro na linkagem

Tags: c, compilação

Estou utilizado a função "crypt" nesse seguinte código:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *key = "rdf";
    char *salt = "50";
    char *hash = crypt(key, salt);

    printf("%s\n", hash);
}
```

e estou obtendo esse erro na hora da  compilação :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse erro não é de compilação, é de linkagem (sim, parece pedantismo, mas é bom conhecer a diferença, tem várias respostas aqui sobre linkedição e o processo de montagem final do executável). Algum `-lmylib` está faltando, aparentemente. Não estou acostumado a trabalhar com `unistd.h`

Comment: just compile like this gcc test.c -o test -l crytp

Answer (score 0):

Eu dei uma boa pesquisada e acho que encontrei uma solução pro teu problema.

De acordo com esse [site](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/unistd.h.html) quando você usa um compilador `ISO C`, é preciso declarar o protótipo da função. Acredito que esse é o seu caso.

Então, de acordo com o mesmo, teria que fazer assim:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Declaração do protótipo da função
char *crypt(const char *, const char *);

int main(void)
{
    char *key = "rdf";
    char *salt = "50";
    char *hash = crypt(key, salt);

    printf("%s\n", hash);
}
```